# Are there any files that can't be checked out?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, check-out

Using SharePoint 2013 are there any file types that can't be checked out and edited?

I was surprised to learn that I could open an Adobe Photoshop .psd file from within SharePoint. After I selected the check out option I was given the Adobe Photoshop icon to choose. I thought only Microsoft files could be checked out.

I know PDF files cannot be edited for obvious reasons. But they can be checked out.

So I ask you again, :) Are there any files that SharePoint 2013 will not allow me to check out?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any item in a library can be checked out regardless of what file type it is. Microsoft Office files go one step further by allowing you to check files in and out from the desktop application but other than that the check out/in is controlled via SharePoint itself and has nothing to do with whether you can actually modify the file or not (as you've noticed with the PDF files).

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Top-questions-about-check-out-check-in-and-versions-7e941339-e972-4c7a-a79a-80a1fcf84076

Comment: When I check out the pdf it only opens the pdf in my browser and not Adobe Acrobat. Why?
It allows me to open the Photoshop file but not the InDesign and Illustrator file. Why? Thanks.

Comment: SharePoint libraries have specific settings to either open the files in the browser (if possible - browser-enabled documents) or using client-side applications. The default is to open in the browser where possible so that's why your PDFs are opening up in the browser instead of Acrobat. If you go to the library settings and then the Advanced Settings of the page you can switch between Open in client and Open in Browser.

Comment: I found this: http://indesignsecrets.com/topic/indesign-and-sharepoint-2013# relating to opening InDesign files and it seems it is currently unsupported due to the way InDesign works. I suspect you may need to do a similar workaround by downloading the files locally, working on them and then saving back or you could also open the library in explorer mode (SP 2010) or use OneDrive for Business to sync a local copy of the file to your PC (SP 2013 & 2016).